# Trying to conversion a view from oracle to PostgreSQL getting error relation "sys.dba_data_files" does not exist

Tags: postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vtot_space (tablespace_name, tbytes) 
AS 
SELECT  tablespace_name, sum(bytes) as tbytes
FROM sys.dba_data_files
group by tablespace_name
order by 1;
```

Comment: Please explain what the view is supposed to be doing.  Views that reference system tables are unusual and certainly are not likely to be portable across different databases (even the more standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views have significant differences across databases).

Comment: make the view's code executable so that i can run the postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

In postgress, to find the `tablespace` and its size you need following query:

```
SELECT spcname as tablespace_name,    
       pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size(spcname)) as tbytes
FROM pg_tablespace;
```

Comment: a lot of Thanks. Working perfectly.

Comment: If it solved your issue then you can accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved.